# Not able to access data return from service in angular class

Tags: angular, typescript

Unable to access data returned from service in angular component.

1. I have following service code.

```ts
getData(fromDate: string, toDate: string): Observable<WfAverageTime[]>
  {
   const url ="http://testApi/getData"
   return this.http.get<someObject[]>(url);
 }
```

2. Following component code

```ts
loadData(fromDate, toDate) {
  let resp = this.testService.getData(fromDate, toDate);
  resp.subscribe((reportData) => {
    this.DataSource.data = reportData as someObject[];
    this.data1 = reportData;
  })
```

`data1` is class level variable. I am unable to use this value in any other function of class. It is being assigned but still not able to access as `this.data1` in other methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put logic where you would like to use that variable inside of that subscribe because it happens **async** so:

````
resp.pipe(
  tap((reportData ) => { ```logic``` })
).subscribe((reportData)=> {this.DataSource.data = reportData as someObject[];
    this.data1 = reportData;
    ```logic```
});
````

Alternatively you can use that value in child component where it would be resolved:

```
public reportData = this.testService.getData(fromDate, toDate);
```

and than in html:

```
<child-component [model]="reportData"></child-component>
```

And than you can use @Input set ... or ngOnChanges to implement logic.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular HTTP client's `get` method is an asynchronous method which essentially means the code execution does not wait until the service call returns the data. The code within the `subscribe` callback will only be executed when the data has been fetched.

So, even though `data1` is a class property it stays undefined until the service call completes and the code execution reaches the `subscribe` callback.

For correctly accessing the values you have to execute your logic that needs the `data1` property from within the `subscribe` callback.

```
loadData(fromDate, toDate) { 
let resp = this.testService.getData(fromDate, toDate);
resp.subscribe((reportData) => {
this.DataSource.data = reportData as someObject[];
this.data1 = reportData; 
// data1 becomes available at this point.
// Call the    methods that use data1 here
})
```